# Is there something like except in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, except

How is this possible? Following construction does not work:

```
$('.multibutton').click(function(event) {

    //.. some stuff before

    $(this).next('.menu').slideDown( "slow");

    // hide all other menus except this.next.menu
    $('.menu :not(this.next)').hide();

    //.. some stuff after
});
```

thank you

Comment: The method is... drumroll please... [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Can you explain what you are attempting to do? Psuedo code isn't very helpful.

Comment: @Juhana: see the code please before you comment..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the menu is next to .multibutton, not in its scope, therefore I need a :not-Filter for the menu, which is next.to (this clicked)

Comment: @user2819288 Are you saying that `.not()` won't do what you want? Please read the documentation before you comment...

Comment: @adeneo thank you but (I do not know why), it is not working too..

Comment: @Juhana maybe my title has been chosen to be somewhat unhappy, but if you see the code, it is better understandable, but thank you for your feedback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.multibutton').click(function(event) {

    //.. some stuff before

    var elem = $(this).next('.menu').slideDown( "slow");

    // hide all other menus except this.next.menu
    $('.menu').not(elem).hide();

    //.. some stuff after
});
```

Comment: trying.. does unfortunately not work here is the code now online: http://jsfiddle.net/fhN3H/1/

Comment: @user2819288 - what the heck is that suppose to be? In the global context `this` is the `window`, and it has no next `menu` ?

Comment: @adeno: yes!! thank you very much, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery.not() function to get a list of the elements **not including** the items specified :

```
$('.multibutton').click(function(event) {

    //.. some stuff before

    $(this).next('.menu').slideDown( "slow");

    // hide all other menus except this.next.menu
    $('.menu').not($(this).next()).hide();

    //.. some stuff after
});
```

More information on [jQuery.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: trying.. does unfortunately not work here is the code now online: http://jsfiddle.net/fhN3H/1/